# IDE-like software for writing plain-English documents

Tags: microsoft-word, ide, productivity

I am looking for a software to write documents with features similar to [IDEs for developers](https://www.google.nl/search?q=ide%20integrated%20development%20environment&espv=2&biw=1216&bih=681&source=lnms&tbm=isch), but that would be optimized for writing documents in plain English. For instance:

- **Completion**: if I start writing a word I get a relevant suggestions to choose from

[image]

- **Rewriting**: I can rewrite a word (or group of words) and have it changed throughout all my documents

[image]

- **Coloring**: I can define certain word types and have them colored differently so they are easily recognizable when I read

[image]

This software should also contain some features of a normal word/text editor (otherwise I would just use an IDE):

- Spell Checker
- Typography options (e.g. titles vs. subtitles vs. paragraph)
- Page marks to get an idea of document size

**Are there any softare like that out there?**

*Did a quick search for things like `IDE for writing normal documents`, `Smart text editor` but wasn't getting anywhere so thought I would ask here*

Comment: It's probably not as automatic as you would like, but you can do this all pretty well in MS word. Find and replace can highlight matches, autocomplete is available, and has all of the page formatting, typographic settings, and spell check you could ever want

Comment: And also in [Libre Office writer](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/writer/), which is free (and can import/export MS word documents)

Answer (score 1):

## [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com)

I know this is mainly intended for programming, but according to its description, it is a

> sophisticated text editor for code, markup, and *prose*.

(emphasis mine, of course)

It has the ability to [spell check by default](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/auto-spell-check-sublime-3/12930), [replace in multiple files](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html), and [there is a plugin](https://github.com/Zinggi/DictionaryAutoComplete) allowing you to autocomplete in plain text files. Screenshot: [DictionaryAutoComplete plugin](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a1f6df9bcddb26b5d4a2dd54947560cfbdf5ac99/68747470733a2f2f6c68332e676f6f676c6575736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f2d7834594d37764a312d57342f555856734846356c2d6f492f414141414141414141566b2f696e3361516367376a45492f733837322f342e676966).

You can [define a custom syntax](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) or edit an existing one to highlight words of your choice.

As for text formatting, I recommend you use [markdown](http://www.markdowntutorial.com/) and [this plugin](https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing), which improves the syntax definition and displays the result as you edit it. To export it to HTML, for example, use [this additional plugin](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview).

If the autocompleter does not work with markdown (it should), you can turn it on everywhere by adding

```
"auto_complete_selector": "source, text"
```

to your user preferences.

Plugins are amazing.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to meet your last requirement in Sublime Text. If it is very important, you could try asking on the [forums](https://forum.sublimetext.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your OS preference so I'll recommend NeoOffice. An Open Office replacement for Macs. It meets all you stated requirements I think, but only runs on a Mac.